# Stackdriver + Resiliency4j - Value type for metric custom.googleapis.com/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/calls must be DOUBLE, but is DISTRIBUTION

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, resilience4j

I am using resiliency4j with the version 1.6.1 and java version 11. The Stackdriver metrics are failing with the followig exception

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Value type for metric custom.googleapis.com/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/calls must be DOUBLE, but is DISTRIBUTION.
```

i found this thread https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/942. But this issue is closed and released for 1.5.0. But we still have this issue.